# Modulus of Modulus of z

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

Is the modulus of the modulus of z, simply the modulus of z?

In real analysis, the absolute value of the absolute value of a real number is simply the absolute value of that real number. But I don't see this property for modulus anywhere in my textbook or online.. Can someone verify if this is true or not?

It seems true if I try to evaluate it based on the definition but I want to make sure. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Since $\lvert z\rvert\in[0,\infty)$, yes, $\bigl\lvert\lvert z\rvert\bigr\rvert=\lvert z\rvert$.